Who beat Spock in class rank at the Academy?
Lt. Valeris is "the first Vulcan to graduate at the top of her class." But Spock went to Starfleet Academy, too. So apparently someone graduated in his year with a higher ranking. Is it known, who that was?

I'm guessing he excelled at the sciences and strategy stuff, and failed miserably at the "getting people to like you and not being an arrogant tit" stuff

I suppose the final exam question about feelings was tough for him too

Spock raised an eyebrow. “You are the first Vulcan to achieve such a position of academic excellence. That merit in itself is a valuable achievement.”
“Some would not agree.” Even after hundreds of years, there were still many Vulcans who considered Starfleet to be a human-centric organization of lesser value than the more esoteric, academic pursuits of the Vulcan Science Academy and other, similar institutions. - Cast No Shadow.

Didn't one of the ST reboot films address this and reveal that James T. Kirk was the cadet who graduated above Spock at the Academy?

I suppose, but the non-Kelvin universe (where Valeris is the first top of the class Vulcan) Spock had graduated by the time Kirk was in the academy, Ithink.

Spock is only half Vulcan.

But he considers himself a Vulcan - and he's hardly going to emphasize his human background in casual conversation

Probably Tuvok or Tuvok's father.
